# How to properly copy a row of data from one Access database to another using C#?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datagridview, row

So, I have Launch_data.mdb and Out_data.mdb. 
The data from a table (any) in Launch_data will be loaded in my form to a datagridview. The user will click on a row, and then click on a "Move to" button. The program needs to move that row from Launch_data.mdb to Out_data.mdb. Both databases have the same table names and structures.

Code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   con1.Open();
   using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
   {  
      cmd.Connection = con1;
      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText =
      @"INSERT INTO " + treeView1.SelectedNode.Name + " IN " + System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Out_data.mdb " +
      @"SELECT * FROM " + treeView1.SelectedNode.Name + " WHERE [Added at:] LIKE ('" + SelectedKey + "')";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   con1.Close();
}
```

And con 1 is:

```
OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Launch_data.mdb");
```

When I ran the code, CommandText contained: `"cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO H11 IN C:\\Users\\uidg3149\\Desktop\\PPAP Area management\\PPAP Area management\\bin\\Debug\\Out_data.mdb SELECT * FROM H11 WHERE [Added at:] LIKE ('3/24/2014 2:31:15 PM')""` 
 which for me looks ok (should insert what it should where it should, BUT it gives me `"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."`. I am pretty new to C# and it's the first time I try to do such operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a code that works:

```
cmd.CommandText =@"INSERT INTO [;DATABASE="+ System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Out_data.mdb]." + treeView1.SelectedNode.Name +
                 @" SELECT " + treeView1.SelectedNode.Name + ".* FROM " + treeView1.SelectedNode.Name + " WHERE (H11.[Added at:] = (#" + SelectedKey + "#))";
```

And btw @HansUp you can do it with "LIKE" and " '' " (instead of " ## ") too.

Answer (score 1):

You need two connections. A connection to read the data from your first database and populate your datagridview, then a second connection to write data to your Out_data database.

Create parameters for your insert query by getting the values from your selected row by doing something like this.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0]);
```

Access doesn't support named parameters so you have to add them in the order you use them in your query. Your INSERT statement might look a bit like this:

```
"Insert into TABLE (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
```